# Storing characters from an input maze file into 2d array (Java)

Tags: java, arrays

I'm having trouble getting the correct values into a 2d array.

My code is supposed to solve mazes. It reads the maze structure from an input .txt file, arranges the structure into a 2d array, and then draws the maze into a drawing panel, which will then animate a solution. I am stuck on getting the structure into the array.

My code reads from an input file like this:

```
2 3
+-+-+-+
|S|   |
+ + + +
|   |E|
+-+-+-+
```

The first 2 numbers are the height and width of the maze. So, this maze has a height of 2 rows and a width of 3 columns.

Here is my code so far.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class MazeSolver {

   // The name of the file describing the maze
   static String mazefile;
   static int width;
   static int height;
   static int arrayWidth;
   static int arrayHeight;
   static char[][] mazeArrays;   
   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
      if (handleArguments(args)) {

         mazeArrays = readMazeFile(mazefile, arrayHeight, arrayWidth);
         System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(mazeArrays));
         DrawMaze.draw(mazeArrays, height, width);

         if (solveMaze())
            System.out.println("Solved!");
         else
            System.out.println("Maze has no solution.");
      }
      else {
      System.out.println("The arguments are invalid.");
      }
   }

   // Handle the input arguments
   static boolean handleArguments(String[] args) {
      if (args.length > 4 || args.length < 1) {
         System.out.println("There are too many or too few command line arguments");
         return false;
      }
      if (args.length == 1) {
         mazefile = args[0];
         File file = new File(mazefile);
         if (!file.canRead()) {
            return false;
         }
         return true;
      }
      if (args.length == 2) {
         mazefile = args[0];
         File file = new File(mazefile);
         if (!file.canRead()) {
            return false;
         }
         int cellsize = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
         if (cellsize < 10) {
            return false;
         }
         return true;
      }
      if (args.length == 3) {
         mazefile = args[0];
         File file = new File(mazefile);
         if (!file.canRead()) {
            return false;
         }
         int cellsize = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
         int borderwidth = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
         if (borderwidth < 5) {
            return false;
         }
         return true;
      }
      if (args.length == 4) {
         mazefile = args[0];
         File file = new File(mazefile);
         if (!file.canRead()) {
            return false;
         }
         int cellsize = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
         int borderwidth = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
         int sleeptime = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
         if (sleeptime < 0 || sleeptime > 10000) {
            return false;
         }
         return true;
      }   
      return false;
   }

   // Read the file describing the maze.
   static char[][] readMazeFile(String mazefile, int arrayHeight, int arrayWidth) throws FileNotFoundException {

      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(mazefile));
      height = scanner.nextInt();
      System.out.println(height);
      width = scanner.nextInt();
      System.out.println(width);
      arrayHeight = 2 * height + 1;
      arrayWidth = 2 * width + 1;
      char[][] mazeArrays = new char[arrayHeight][arrayWidth];
      while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
         String line = scanner.nextLine();
         System.out.println(line);
         for (int row = 0; row < arrayHeight; row++) {
           for (int col = 0; col < line.length(); col++) {
               mazeArrays[row][col] = line.charAt(col);




           }
         }



      }return mazeArrays;

   }

   // Solve the maze.      
   static boolean solveMaze() {
      return true;
   }
}
```

The issue is in the method `readMazeFile`

Here is the output:

```
2
3

+-+-+-+
|S|   |
+ + + +
|   |E|
+-+-+-+
[[+, -, +, -, +, -, +], [+, -, +, -, +, -, +], [+, -, +, -, +, -, +], [+, -, +, -, +, -, +], [+, -, +, -, +, -, +]]
Solved!
```

It looks like my problem is that the scanner never moves to the next line, but I believe I'm writing it correctly. The 2d array is storing the first line correctly, but does not move on to " |S|    |" and after.

I also am anticipating an issue with storing white space into the array.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are seeing in the output is the last line of the input, not the first. This is because you are storing each line in every row of the maze:

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println(line);
    for (int row = 0; row < arrayHeight; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < line.length(); col++) {
            mazeArrays[row][col] = line.charAt(col);
        }
    }
}
```

I suspect you intended:

```
for (int row = 0; row < arrayHeight; row++) {
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println(line);
    for (int col = 0; col < arrayWidth; col++) {
        mazeArrays[row][col] = line.charAt(col);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It works until the second for loop, where mazeArrays[row][col] = line.charAt(co); raises an exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5

Comment: The '5' in the exception means that it's trying to store something in row 5 when you have only allocated rows 0 - 4 (i.e. size 5 = 2 * 2 + 1). I presume that is because it's reading an extra line. The easy way to stop it is to test against arrayHeight and arrayWidth instead of `hasNextLine`. I'll change the code.

Comment: Thank you! That improved the output. And thank you for explaining what the 5 represented. If you don't mind continuing, the array now holds '0000' in mazeArrays[0][0-6 (inclusive)], and then is stored correctly. So the maze structure in the array begins at [1][0]. Is it reading an empty line?

Comment: Yes I suspect that's what it's doing - which would also explain the index out of  bounds exception. You just need to add a `scanner.nextLine()` before the loop to jump over the blank line.